# Not able to rename jar file using maven jar plugin

Tags: java, maven

I have a maven project with packaging as war but I want to generate its jar as well so I am using the following plugin:

```
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
                <artifactId>maven-jar-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>3.1.0</version>
                <configuration>
                    <classifier>classes</classifier>
                    <finalName>${project.artifactId}-${project.version}</finalName>
                </configuration>
                <executions>
                    <execution>
                        <id>package-jar</id>
                        <phase>package</phase>
                        <goals>
                            <goal>jar</goal>
                        </goals>
                    </execution>
                </executions>
            </plugin>
```

Problem:

1) Name of the jar is coming as `artifact-version-classes.jar` but I do not want "classes" in the jar name, it should be like `artifact-version.jar`.

If I remove  tag then I am getting following error:

> Failed to execute goal
>   org.apache.maven.plugins:maven-jar-plugin:3.1.0:jar (package-jar) on
>   project xyz: You have to use a classifier to attach supplemental
>   artifacts to the project instead of replacing them.

Please guide how to achieve this.

Comment: Wrong way...use the configuration of [maven-war-plugin](https://maven.apache.org/plugins/maven-war-plugin/war-mojo.html#attachClasses) `archiveClasses`/`attachClasses` and and create a separate jar file...apart from that `finalName` for maven-jar-plugin does not exist as configuration...

Comment: My bet is, if you properly split your project in Maven modules, this problem vanishes...

Comment: Thanks khmarbaise! I am using the following plugin now:
                     <plugin>
    <artifactId>maven-war-plugin</artifactId>
    <version>3.2.2</version>
    <configuration>
     <attachClasses>false</attachClasses>
    <outputFileNameMapping>${artifactId}-${project.version}.jar</outputFileNameMapping>
    </configuration>
   </plugin>

Can you please let me know how I can remove "classes" from the generated jar name.

Comment: Why are you using outputFileNameMapping? Furthermore the resulting artifact is an artifact with a classifier which can be consumed by other project as a dependency...the question is why you like to remove the classifier `classes` which is not possible cause the main artifact is the resulting `.war` file...otherwise those will clash ....

Comment: ok! I got your point thank you so much for helping me.